# How can i get the location of certain rows by using the index of a series with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use the high_accidents(Pandas Series) index which is a list of cities to get the rows of the dataframe that match the df["City"] value.

```
count_city = df["City"].value_counts()

high_accidents = count_city[count_city >= 1000]

new_df = df.loc[df["City"].values == high_accidents.index]
```

This returns ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here df['City'].values will give your an array of cities and high_accidents.index is of pandas.index type. So the error message is shown that length must match to compare.

To get your desired result you can modify the code as following:-

```
count_city = df["City"].value_counts()

high_accidents = count_city[count_city >= 1000]

new_df = df.loc[df["City"].isin(high_accidents.index)]
```